# Use a username as key in firebase for storing users

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to have a username/password login system instead of email/password. What I am currently doing, is to take the username and append a '@domain.com' at the end and register the user on firebase as an email/password account.

In my firebase database, I am storing the user information under 'userProfiles/$uid'. However, given only the username of a user, I need to first access another node to lookup the uid and then use that to access the user data.

My question is: are there any disadvantages in just storing the user data under each username instead? In my security rules, I can then do this:

```
$username + '@domain.com' === auth.token.email
```

Most of the time, I have direct access to the user's uid. However, there is the case where I want to reset a user's password(I had to implement it myself because I am using the usernames as emails in firebase) and I only have access to the username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Update***

As pointed out in the comments since users are being signed up using `username +  '@domain.com'` Firebase will prevent duplicate usernames because it won't allow two separate users to sign up with the same email. Once your user is created you can write the username to the database and there won't be any collisions. Keep in mind that this problem can become more difficult **if users are allowed to change their username**. You'll have to check the newly requested username against the existing usernames to determine if the requested name already exists. Lastly, don't forget Firebase is case sensitive so you might want to cast all usernames to lower/uppercase and trim the trailing white space before you upload them.

The biggest problem I can think of is that uid's are guaranteed to be unique by Firebase so there can't be any duplicates. If you store everything by username you'll have to make sure there are no duplicate usernames when users sign up. So you have to make an area of the database that can be read from by unauthenticated users to check the requested username against existing usernames.

You have to think about how you're going to access the data most of the time. Additionally, if you denormalize the user data (store it under uid & username) you have to make sure that both copies stay in sync. It's probably easier to just store `username -> uid` so that you have a mapping to get to the user data if you only have the username. This isn't going to happen that often and the extra nested query isn't going to make much of a performance difference.

Comment: Won't firebase take care of the usernames being unique since I am also registering them on firebase in the format <username>@domain.com with '@domain.com' being common in all users?

Comment: That seems correct. I don't think you can create two users with the same email address. So if you write the username data after the user is created you won't have the problem of keeping usernames unique.